# Adding words to one of many spellfiles

Tags: spell-checking

Say I am mixing English and German in my documents and have my spelllang variable set accordingly. How do I indicate, when I want to mark a word as good, to which spellfile it is to be added?

Comment: If you provide a list of `spellfile`s, `zg` takes a count to decide which spellfile to add to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The credits goes to @muru for this answer since [his comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6406/adding-words-to-one-of-many-spellfiles#comment10095_6406) gave the solution 3 months ago. I write this answer to let users searching for this question know that it has a solution.

The variable `spellfile` may be a comma separated line of files. Those files are used to add "good words".

The command `zg` allows to add a "good word" to the files in `spellfile`. By default the good word will be added to the first entry of `spellfile` but when used with a count the command will add the word to the `n`th file listed in `spellfile`.